# How to properly print out a CSV file in python

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to scrape some data, write that data to a CSV file, then import that CSV file into R to do some analysis on it.  This is more of a personal project to learn python and R, and I'm having some trouble printing to the CSV file.  What I have now prints out in a completely chaotic fashion and R really can't use the data in the way I want it to.  Does anyone have any tips? Here is the code for the csv file:

```
with open('cdc_data.csv','w', newline='',) as f:
   i = 0
   fieldnames = ['Country', 'Infected', 'Deaths']
   thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
   print("Country /", end=' ')
   print("Infected /", end=' ')
   print("Deaths /", end=' ')
   print("Location:", end=' ')
   print(" ")
   thewriter.writeheader()
   for x in infectionData:
      while i <= 83:
         print(infectionData[i], end=' ')
         thewriter.writerow({'Country': infectionData[i]})
         i += 1
         print(infectionData[i], end=' ')
         thewriter.writerow({'Infected': infectionData[i]})
         i += 1
         print(infectionData[i], end=' ')
         thewriter.writerow({'Deaths': infectionData[i]})
         i += 1
         print(infectionData[i])
        # thewriter.writerow({'Location': infectionData[i]})
         i += 1
```

I added what the current output looks now, I'm trying to get it so it looks more like this
Countries / Infected / Deaths / Location
China     /  1771    /  170   /  Asia
etc

Here is what print(infectedData) outputs:

```
['China', '7,711', '170', 'Asia', 'Thailand', '14', '0', 'Asia', 'Hong Kong', '11', '0', 'Asia', 'Taiwan', '8', '0', 'Asia', 'Macau', '7', '0', 'Asia', 'Malaysia', '7', '0', 'Asia', 'Singapore', '10', '0', 'Asia', 'Japan', '8'
```

and keeps going

[Image of CSV output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27iIH.png)

Comment: What format is `infectionData` in?

Comment: Check out pythons [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to write to csv file

Comment: infectionData is an arrary of 83 strings @MarkSnyder

Comment: What do the strings look like? And what does the current output look like, and what should it look like?

Comment: @MarkSnyder I updated the information, I think I explained the strings correctly.

Comment: This is chaotic indeed. Please include a bit of print(infectionData)'s output to see your format. (is it a list of dicts or what?) You don't use your x variable that supposedly iterates through your data. You also semi-randomly increase i's value. I think you need only one thewriter.writerow call, with a bit bigger dict, but I'm not sure of your input format.

Comment: @Tan42: I don't think your report on infectionData's format is correct. If there were [ and ] characters, those would show up in your spreadsheet. [...] also shows a list in python, that's why I'd prefer a print(infectionData) output (or at least the first few rows).

Comment: Hi thanks for all of the feedback, I have updated with a printout to help!  Sorry about that @Nyos

Comment: @Tan42: Fixed my code. Also note that if R doesn't like this csv dialect (quotes, newlines, etc.) you can try unix/excel variants as well by adding e.g. dialect='excel' or dialect='unix' to DictWriter's parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

def remove_comma(s):
  return s.replace(',', '')

def export_to_csv(data,filename='cdc_data.csv'):
  with open(filename,'w', newline='',) as f:
    fieldnames = ['Country', 'Infected', 'Deaths', 'Location']
    thewriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    print(' / '.join(fieldnames))
    thewriter.writeheader()
    i=0
    while i+3<len(data):
      x=data[i:i+4]
      x[1]=remove_comma(x[1])
      x[2]=remove_comma(x[2])
      thewriter.writerow({'Country': x[0],'Infected':x[1],'Deaths':x[2],'Location':x[3]})
      print(' '.join([str(val) for val in x]))
      i+=4

#call it like:
infectionData=['China', '7,711', '170', 'Asia', 'Thailand', '14', '0', 'Asia', 'Hong Kong', '11', '0', 'Asia', 'Taiwan', '8', '0', 'Asia', 'Macau', '7', '0', 'Asia', 'Malaysia', '7', '0', 'Asia', 'Singapore', '10', '0', 'Asia']
export_to_csv(infectionData)
```

Or you can also add a filename if the default is not okay.